# storing array of strings in postgres using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, arrays, postgresql, sequelize.js

I currently have a posts table and a users table.

My Posts model:

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
 },
 title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
images: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
```

My Users model:

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
name: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
```

Each user can have many posts and each post can only have 1 user.

Association:

```
Users.hasMany(Posts, {
 foreignKey: "id",
});

 Posts.belongsTo(Users, {
 foreignKey: "id",
 });
```

In my posts table images is a string, a user can post many images in one post (hence an array of filename of images).

in my post method, I am using JSON.stringify to store the images filename as a string in the database as without JSON.stringify i get an error saying images cannot be an object or array. After hours of research i found that it is not best practise to use JSON.stringify on an array.

If that is correct, then how should i store my array of filename of images in Postgres using sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

> In my posts table images is a string, a user can post many images in one post (hence an array of filename of images).

Excuse me if I get preachy about this, but you should mend your evil ways and return to the golden path of normalized relational data modelling.

It may seem intuitive to store a relationship as an array of "foreign keys", but I promise you that you will suffer in the long run:

- you cannot enforce the relationship with a constraint, which leads to inconsistencies
- any attempt to join the tables via that relationship will lead to unnecessarily complicated SQL statements that won't perform and scale well
- adding a new relationship means modifying (that is, rewriting) a potentially large table row

Use a "junction table" to model such relationships: such a table consists of two foreign keys, each pointing to one of the tables that are related. An entry means that the two referred rows are related.

If an image can only belong to a single post, the solution is even simpler: add a foreign key constraint to the `images` table.

Comment: should it be something like this Images.belongsTo(Posts, {
  foreignKey: "postId",
});

Posts.hasMany(Images, {
  foreignKey: "postId",
});

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have the faintest idea about Javascript or the ORMs you are using.

Comment: Im using Sequelize ORM

Comment: Yes, you tagged that as you should, but since I don't know this tool, I cannot tell you how to create a foreign key constraint with it.